# Django - Get objects from a squared many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I'm starting a Django project with models like:

Vendor <- many to many -> Product <- many to many -> Category

Is there an efficient way to get all the categories linked to the products of a vendor ?

Current inefficient way:

1. Get all the products of a specific vendor
2. For all products get their specific categories
3. Remove duplicates of the categories list

If possible I would like to avoid creating a fake many-to-many relation between Category and Vendor.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I was not sure how to name this question, if you think of a better title feel free to change it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is always to start from the model you want to get, ie Category. So, assuming your relations are called `product` and `vendor`, and you have a Vendor object called `my_vendor`:

```
Category.objects.filter(product__vendor=my_vendor)
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you very much !